# Get column names of a table in 1 row without data from that table - Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Hello StackOverflow community,

Could you please tell me can I get information about column names of a table in 1 row using `Firebird`? **[*]**

What I'd like to achieve is the following using `Postgres`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0;
```

Above statement would return 0 rows, but will contain the header

```
id | data
---+-------
(0 rows)
```

**[*]** I need a similar way (taken from example above) in Firebird to obtain information about columns, since I'm using it external tool, so I need to provide a dynamically built schema for dynamic queries. This implies, that I'm not looking for a solution using system tables like `rdb$relation_fields`.

Adding `WHERE` condition with dummy value does not apply in my case. I'm looking for something like `SELECT FIRST 0 ...`. Does it even exist?

**edited**: Yes, it does. Interactive Firebird Client *doesn't show up anything*, but it does indeed return the "header". This may be confusing for some of us that use psql console which yields 0 rows, but does contain the "header" itself.

Comment: I have edited my question with some additional information for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird supports limiting the result set - but the syntax is a bit different:

```
SELECT FIRST 0 * 
FROM table_name;
```

This is part of the Firebird FAQ: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq111/

Comment: I've accepted this answer, since it does apply the most.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
select * from (
    [any query here]
) where 1=0
```

Comment: What about the modified answer?

Comment: @ConsiderMe: the solution with a derived table is **not** "tool specific" (whatever that is supposed to mean) - it's standard SQL

Comment: Still not getting what the use case is where this can't be applied.